# Adding Image's to a Code first Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, relational-database, code-first

Quick question I am new to Visual Studio and ASP.net web forms.

I have build a database using the code first method and I am wondering if it is possible to add images into a database and if so how and then how would i link them

Here is the variables, as you can see I have a mix of strings and ints

And now I am wondering if you can add an image value in the same way

```
    public string SuperName { get; set; }
    public string NormalName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int NumAppearances { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

And here is all the variables filled in

```
 IList<Character> defaultCharacters1 = new List<Character>();
            defaultCharacters1.Add(new Character() { SuperName = "Iron Man", NormalName = "Tony Stark", Age = 49, Role = "Hero", Location = "New York", NumAppearances = 5, Description = "An American billionaire playboy, industrialist, and ingenious engineer, Tony Stark suffers a severe chest injury during a kidnapping in which his captors attempt to force him to build a weapon of mass destruction. He instead creates a powered suit of armor to save his life and escape captivity. Later, Stark augments his suit with weapons and other technological devices he designed through his company, Stark Industries. He uses the suit and successive versions to protect the world as Iron Man." });
```

Also here is current screen shot of my database displaying the information

[image]

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to upload your images to an external storage, like Azure Blob storage (you get backup of your images if they are there) for example, and then save the link to this blob in your SQL through EF.

Saving BLOBs in SQL (the image is a BLOB) may lead to bad fragmentation and will evantually slow down the database. That is why BLOBs are stored outside the SQL DB.

Another drawback of images sitting in the DB is that you will put a lot of traffinc from back to front - throughout your app - and you will slow down your site a lot. On the contrary if you place them in external BLOB storage you will server a link which the broser will load from a different location increasing the overall speed of your site.

So dont store images in SQL even though you can store them in [binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188362.aspx) column or even in a varchar column after base64 encoding. (You have never heard me suggesting that :) ). Store them on some kind of BLOB storage - Azure, Amazon, Picasa,... whatever and only save their URLs in the SQL db.

Comment: First off thank you for all the information, but I am very new to all this, and was just looking for a way to add images to my database variable so when I am filling it out i just enter the scr path of an image and have it show up, is that possible ?

Comment: It is absolutely possible :) If you are just starting than you can try out [this tutorial ](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/9-working-with-images)

Comment: can u maybe show me an example of that i was think something like public Image cImage {get, set} and then something like cImage = "src =Images/cImage " would that work ?